# JPA + JUnit. @OneToOne binding inside a transaction in

Tags: java, spring, jpa, junit, transactions

I use JUnit + Spring + JPA

I have two entities with @OneToOne relationship:

```
@Entity
public class Principal {
//...
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;
//...
}

@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {
//...
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user")
    private Principal principal;
//...
}
```

And I have missunderstending useing them inside a transaction in my JUnit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {JPATestConfig.class})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = false)
public class JpaTest {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;
    private Long userId;
    String jstl = "SELECT DISTINCT a FROM User a WHERE a.id = :id";

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void test() {
        User user = new User();
        em.persist(user);
        Principal principal = new Principal();
        principal.setUser(user);
        em.persist(principal);

        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(jstl, User.class);
        query.setParameter("id", user.getId());
        User user1 = query.getSingleResult();
        //... In this point I have 
        //... user1.principal == null
    }
    @After
    @Transactional
    public void anotherTest(){
        TypedQuery<User> query = em.createQuery(jstl, User.class);
        query.setParameter("id", userId);
        User user1 = query.getSingleResult();
        //... different transaction, but still user1.principal == null 
    }
}
```

Why don't can I take @OneToOne parameter of just created and persisted entity inside the same jUnit @Transactional test(even in same jUnit test-class)?

But DB after test has filled right, so I can start another test in which binding of existed entities is successful.

**EDIT**

OK,

```
em.persist(principal);
em.flush();
em.clear();
```

helps enough, but I still can't understend why binding didn't work in `anotherTest()`?

EntityManager flush everithing itself when transaction(`test()`) ends, doesn't it?

Comment: Have you tried setting the principal on the user? right now you are assigning only the other side of the relation

Comment: As kostja said, you must set both sides of your bidirectional relationship or the entity is out of sync with what is in the database.  JPA doesn't maintain relationships for you, so they will stay out of sync until the entity is refreshed from the database.  Depending on your JPA provider, the entity might be out of synch in the EM and the 2nd level cache if one is used.

Comment: @Chris, thanks for explanation. I see, that JPA doesn't maintain relationships for me (and it's sad). But what about transactions? I see only one way how it could be. After transaction in `test()` properly ends(on DB-level), Hibernate takes data from cache (but not from DB) in `anotherTest()`. Am I right?